# Steam distillation of açaí powder

Tags: home-experiment, distillation

I have a steam distillation setup with the flask for boiling the açaí powder with distilled water. Are you able to extract the essential oil from the boiling material?

Answer (score 2):

[Wiki on açaí oil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%C3%A7a%C3%AD_oil)

Açaí  oil is obtained by cold pressing.  Steam distillation may be able to extract compounds like vanillic acid but may not get the anthocyanins or the triglycerides.  Many of the health benefits are from the healthy triglycerides and the anthocyanins.

Comment: Does the cold pressing have to be done with the berries only or can you do it with the acai powder?